# Apply CSS hierarchically on all child elements except one

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this CSS rule:

```
.x-pp-plan , .x-pp-plan * {
  font: normal normal normal 15px/120% Arial;
  color: #666;
}
```

related to this component hierarchy:

[image]

How can I apply this styling to all components (*) EXCEPT `.performance-component`?

I already tried `*:not(.performance-component)` but it not worked.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please include the html rather than an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the class & try giving it an `id="yourID"`
and then give it your desired styling like this

```css
#yourID{
   // the desired styles
}
```

its not what more experienced developers would recommend but its a quick fix for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate style declaration for the div you want styled differently. Also, you don't need the `.x-pp-plan *` since all children of `.x-pp-plan` should already inherit the parent's styles.

```
.x-pp-plan {
  font: normal normal normal 15px/120% Arial;
  color: #666;
}

.x-pp-plan .perfomance-component {
  font: 'Comic Sans';
  color: red;
}
```